# Is possible to add column(s) to an existing table using the google-cloud-java SDK

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Is possible to add column(s) to an existing table using the google-cloud-java SDK ?

BigQuery interface does have a [update](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.9.3/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQuery.html#update-com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableInfo-com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery.TableOption...-) method, but it seems only able to table's metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, it sure is. Use the `update` method and provide the new schema. You need to provide the entire schema i.e. the old and new column(s). `null` will be inserted for the new column(s) values.

This example will add `column_2` to the existing table which already has `column_1`:

```
String datasetName = "test";
String tableName = "foo";
Table oldTable = bigQuery.getTable(datasetName, tableName);

Field col1 = Field.of("column_1", Field.Type.string());
Field col2 = Field.of("column_2", Field.Type.string());
Schema schema = Schema.of(col1, col2);
TableInfo tableInfo = oldTable.toBuilder().setDefinition(StandardTableDefinition.of(schema)).build();
bigQuery.update(tableInfo);
```

[image]

http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.9.3/apidocs/?com/google/cloud/bigquery/package-summary.html